# integrate powershell with angular

Tags: angular, powershell, porting

I am trying to develop the frontend of a web application using Angular and integrate it with an already existing 'backend' that uses Powershell. The Powershell 'backend' was part of a desktop application but I would like to use it as a web application.
How do I integrate this Powershell 'backend' with Angular? Are there Powershell modules that can help with this?

Comment: I am not even sure how you would use angular to write a backend, that is the first I heard of using it for that purpose. To that end I have also never heard of it integrating with powershell and am not sure what the benefit would be (what is the use case for angular doing something in powershell).

Comment: my application is already done with powershell it is an (active directory desktop application ) and i'm trying to convert this desktop application to a web application  with angular

Comment: Angular is a framework that is dependent on a web browser and that is the context in which it executes. There is no way that it can directly execute powershell scripts that I am aware of. You would have to create an intermediary layer to serve as the backend that would do that for you. This could be anything from node.js to a web api end point.

Comment: You could look at [Polaris](https://powershell.github.io/Polaris/) to create an API that can be called by Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a web technology that executes in the context of a browser. You will need to either port the Powershell portion of the code to a language that can act as a web server such as node.js, python, ruby etc.. OR create an API layer to interface with the Powershell logic.

I personally would look at porting the Powershell code to Node.js and try to make that new backend logic platform agnostic.